# MessageSource always returns the default message

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to inject text message using MessageSource in Spring. The program I wrote compiles fine, but it always printing out the default message instead of fetching the right values from .properties file. I have no clues at all.

Here's the Circle class that tries to inject the text:

```
 @Component
    public class Circle implements Shape {

        @Resource
        private Point center;
        @Autowired
        private MessageSource messageSource;

        public MessageSource getMessageSource() {
            return messageSource;
        }

        public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
            this.messageSource = messageSource;
        }

        public Point getCenter() {
            return center;
        }

        public void setCenter(Point center) {
            this.center = center;
        }

        @Override
        public void draw() {
            System.out.println(this.messageSource.getMessage("greeting", null, "Default Greeting", null));
            System.out.println(this.messageSource.getMessage("draw.circle", new Object[] {center.getX(), center.getY()}, "Required Drawing", null));

        }
```

And here's part of the bean configuration file:

```
...
    <bean id="center" class="java.awt.Point">
        <constructor-arg value="0" />
        <constructor-arg value="-20" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSourse" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename">
                <value>messages</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject.spring"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>
```

And I store the greeting and draw.circle in messages.properties file and wrote a main class. But the outputs are always:

```
Default Greeting  
Required Drawing
```

Does anybody know what can possibly go wrong in my case?

**Update**
Thanks for the advice. I was debugging and seems like something went wrong in here:

```
public String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, String defaultMessage, Locale locale) {
        if (this.parentMessageSource != null) {
            return this.parentMessageSource.getMessage(code, args, defaultMessage, locale);
        }
        else {
            return renderDefaultMessage(defaultMessage, args, locale);
        }
    }
```

this.parentMessageSource is null so it decided to render default message. But I still don't quite understand what is parentMesssageSource and how it can be (not) null?

Comment: where is the messages.properties is located.does it in src folder..

Comment: It is in a folder called properties which is in the same folder as src. However I did try to move it into src to see if it would work.

Comment: could you try like this..create a package(com.messages) in src and put messages.properties in the package...and try this..<bean id="messageSource"
  class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basename" value="/com.messages" />
 </bean>

Comment: I just tried it. Didn't work. Meanwhile I found something through debugging. I've updated my post. See if this would offer any clues for you.. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed it. I was using maven and it might be because I screwed up the file folder structure. So I re-created another maven project with properties and xml file in its default src/main/resources folder. Problem solved!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use **id="messageSource"** instead **id="messageSour*s*e"**.
For all  that use Java configurations, you have to have **"messageSource()"** as a method name

```
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource =
                new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename(I18_PATH_TEMPLATE + "email_welcome");
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resourceBundleMessageSource;
    }
```

Comment: In addition to Alexis' answer, I believe that spring will create a default empty message source if one is not found (in this case with the wrong name) so you don't get an injection error.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the messageSource is not able to pick your messages file. ResourceBundleMessageSource has overriden `toString()` method to display the messageResource configuration. Try using it once. You can also inspect `messageSource` object just after it has been injected with the help of a debugging tool, to check whether it has loaded all the properties successfully or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have mis-spelled the bean id

Instead of '**messageSource**', you have written '**messageSourse**'.

You must have an id of the Message Resource bean, and it should always be 'messageSource'.

Answer (score 0):

The Extension of the Property file should be .properties